# Extracting tag content based on content value using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, html-content-extraction

I have a Html document of the following format.

```
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. Content of the paragraph <i> in italic </i> but not <b> strong </b> <a href="url">ignore</a>.</p>
```

I want to extract the content of paragraph tag, including the content of italic and bold tag but not the content of anchor tag. Also, possible ignoring the Numeric in the beginning.

The expected output is:
Content of the paragraph in italic but not strong.

What is the best way to do it?

Also, the following code snippet returns **TypeError: argument of type 'NoneType' is not iterable**

```
soup = BSoup(page)
for p in soup.findAll('p'):
    if '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' in p.string:
        print p
```

Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code fails because `tag.string` is set if the tag has only one child and that child is `NavigableString`

You can achieve what you want by extracting the `a` tag:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

s = """<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. Content of the paragraph <i> in italic </i> but not <b> strong </b> <a href="url">ignore</a>.</p>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(s, convertEntities=BeautifulSoup.HTML_ENTITIES)

for p in soup.findAll('p'):
    for a in p.findAll('a'):
        a.extract()
    print ''.join(p.findAll(text=True))
```

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the perspicuous reply. It worked like charm.

Answer (score 1):

I think you would just have to iterate through the tags inside `p` and collect the desired strings.

Using [lxml](http://codespeak.net/lxml/), you could use XPath:

```
import lxml.html as LH
import re

content = '''\
<p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. Content of the paragraph <i> in italic </i> but not <b> strong </b> <a href="url">ignore</a>.</p>'''

doc = LH.fromstring(content)
ptext = ''.join(doc.xpath('//p/descendant-or-self::*[not(self::a)]/text()'))
pat = r'^.*\d+.\s*'
print(re.sub(pat,'',ptext))
```

yields:

```
Content of the paragraph  in italic  but not  strong  .
```

Comment: Thanks unutbu for your reply. That regular expression to eliminate the prefix numeric was really useful. I got the answer in BeautifulSoup itself, so need not use the lxml, however, thanks for informing about it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're having regarding `string` is because `string` is, as explained in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/documentation.html#string), only available:

> if a tag has onnly one child node, and that child node is a string

Hence, in your case `p.string` is `None` and you can't iterate over it. To get access to a tag contents you have to use `p.contents` (this is a list that includes the tags) or `p.text` (this is a string with all the tags removed).

In your case, you're probably looking for something like this:

```
>>> ''.join([str(e) for e in soup.p.contents
                    if not isinstance(e, BeautifulSoup.Tag)
                       or e.name != 'a'])
>>> '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;1. Content of the paragraph <i> in italic </i> but not <b> strong </b> .'
```

If you need to also remove the `' ' prefix, I'd use a regular expression to remove that part from the final string.

Comment: Thanks jcollado for your quick reply. The documentation reference and your explanation were enlightening.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text

If you only want the text part of a document or tag, you can use the get_text() method. It returns all the text in a document or beneath a tag, as a single Unicode string. (given in the documentation in the link above)